problem between sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV and scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier
my sklearn version is 1.4.2 and my 0.13.0 , when i want to use gridsreach in classification , i got this error :
ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator KerasClassifier.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasClassifier constructor:
KerasClassifier(activation=relu)
Check the list of available parameters with estimator.get_params().keys()
keras_wr_class = KerasClassifier(build_fn=AnnModel)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=keras_wr_class, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
grid_search.fit(x_train_s,y_train)


It's always good to share executable code. You can share it using gist.github.com

I just ran some small tests on google colab (21/09/20242) : Successfully installed scikeras-0.13.0 scikit-learn-1.5.2 and the problem persists
**
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_container_adapter' from 'sklearn.utils._set_output' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py)
**

To fine-tune hyperparameters using GridSearchCV, begin by installing the
scikeras library. Preprocess your data and define your model. Next, define a
dictionary containing hyperparameter names and their potential values. Wrap
your model within the KerasClassifier class. Finally, pass the wrapped model
and the hyperparameter dictionary to GridSearchCV and initiate the training
process with the fit method. I have implemented GridSearchCv , refer to the
provided gist.
